# Trying to build a 'random text' WordPress plugin. No idea where to start

Tags: wordpress

Here’s what I’ve done in a spreadsheet:

1. I’ve assigned people to one or more categories (ie. male, female, tall, short)
2. I’ve assigned weights to these people (ie. 200 lbs, 120 lbs, 300 lbs)
3. I’ve assigned names to these people (ie. John, Jane, Bill)

Here’s what I need to do in a plugin:

1. Find some way to get my data into it (maybe through an admin interface, or via my spreadsheet)
2. Filter results by one or more categories (ie. only male; only tall + female, etc)
3. From those filtered results, pull 2 or 3 people (as many as I can fit) whose combined weights equal X or less
4. Display the names of those 2 or 3 people as a list to front-end users
5. At the press of a button, randomly generate another 2 or 3 person team

I don’t mind getting my hands dirty, but I don't know where to begin. If  you guys could give me any advice, best practices, code to get me started, or names of plugins that already do this, etc, I’d really appreciate it.

Also, if I’m biting off too much for a complete noob, feel free to let me know. Because if it comes down to it, I’ll just create the teams manually and throw them into a random text plugin, or something.

Answer (score 0):

1. This depends heavily on what format it's in presently.  If it's in a spreadsheet, you can import it pretty easily by saving as a CSV and processing it with [fgetscsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
2. Assuming this is going into MySQL (as most WP plugins do), this is just a SQL query (ie WHERE wp_custom_person_record_weight > 100 AND wp_custom_person_record_name != 'Bill'
3. Same as #2 but with a JOIN and a SUM and a WHERE query against that sum.
4. This is the same SQL query, if you call it through [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) you'll get an array back that you can output on the page
5. Random records can be gleaned a number of ways, either by going through a limit of X,2 where X is a randomly generated number between 0 and the # of records or through MySQL itself (although that is not recommended for performance reasons).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Doing some research on this stuff right now.